# how to stream to hdmi and Airtunes simultaneously pulseaudio

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, hdmi

The ONLY reason I keep my Windows partition is because I can stream simultaneously from my desktop hdmi and one or more Apple Airport Express< I cannot get this to happen with Pulseaudio. It's either HDMI or Airport, but not both. I have "Add virtual output device for simultaneous output.."checked. I see a combined output for HDMI and digital only. Is there a way to manually configure for simultaneous streams?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the RAOP protocol provided by **pulseaudio-module-raop** is quite limited when compared to it's Closed Source counterparts as it

- can not stream to more than 1 Air Port Express
- can not reconnect when the network signal was interrupted
- streams with a 6 seconds delay
- can not stream simultaneously to another audio sink

We have to live with that until someone provides a better solution, or the new raop2 protocol may eventually become available.

Most of all it's the rather long delay that makes simultaneous streams to other audio sinks or for watching movies rather unusuable.